# Error while installing Electron via 'npm install electron'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I'm trying to install electron thorugh npm install electron and I'm getting this error:

```
908 error code 1
909 error path C:\Users\name\Documents\name\Code\code\node_modules\gl
910 error command failed
911 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
912 error prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=20.9.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
912 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
912 error gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
912 error gyp info using node@20.9.0 | win32 | x64
912 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
912 error gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.7.34221.43) found at:
912 error gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
912 error gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
912 error gyp info spawn C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
912 error gyp info spawn args [
912 error gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\name\\Code\\code\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
912 error gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-f',
912 error gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
912 error gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\name\\Code\\code\\node_modules\\gl\\build\\config.gypi',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
912 error gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\name\\Code\\code\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
912 error gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.9.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.9.0',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\name\\Code\\code\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\name\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.9.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\name\\Code\\code\\node_modules\\gl',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
912 error gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\name\\Code\\code\\node_modules\\gl\\build',
912 error gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
912 error gyp info spawn args ]
912 error Traceback (most recent call last):
912 error   File "C:\Users\name\Documents\name\Code\code\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
912 error     import gyp  # noqa: E402
912 error     ^^^^^^^^^^
912 error   File "C:\Users\name\Documents\name\Code\code\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
912 error     import gyp.input
912 error   File "C:\Users\name\Documents\name\Code\code\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 19, in <module>
912 error     from distutils.version import StrictVersion
912 error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
912 error gyp ERR! configure error 
912 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
912 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\name\Documents\name\Code\code\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:325:16)
912 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
912 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
912 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
912 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\name\\Code\\code\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
912 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\name\Documents\name\Code\code\node_modules\gl
912 error gyp ERR! node -v v20.9.0
912 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.0
912 error gyp ERR! not ok
```

This is the first time using node and npm so I am kind of confused on why this error is showing.

I tried doing npm cache clean --force and then installing it again but it did not work. I want to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems that `distutils` isn't installed. You should try to install the `distutils` package.